# Finding the function of a hyperplane given its steepest gradient vector?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Assume that I have some high-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^D$. Assume further that I have a vector $v$ of length $D$, $v \in \mathbb{R}^D$, which we assume points along the steepest gradient of the hyperplane we are looking for.

As a small example, consider the case $D=3$. We can imagine infinitely many planes which include our three-dimensional $v$ (all rotated along $v$), but only one for which $v$ points in the direction of the steepest gradient.

How would I find the function of this hyperplane not only in $D=3$, but also in higher dimensions? (Consider, for example, the vector $v=\left[-1,6,2,-4 \right]^T \in \mathbb{R}^4$ if you want a specific case)

Comment: Assuming that by “gradient” you mean what’s also commonly called “slope,” this only makes sense if you distinguish some direction as “up,” i.e., that you’re considering this hyperplane to be the graph of some linear function $f:\mathbb R^{D-1}\to\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, hyperplanes are equivalent to lines in $R^2$. so they only have one gradient. I do not understand your notion of steepest gradient.

In $R^3$ hyperplanes are defined by the plane equation. Plane equation is defined as dot product of a normal vector to any vector on the plane = 0. You need two information 1) normal vector,W and 2) a point on the plane (if it crosses the origin you could use the zero vector).

This can also be extended to higher dimensions.

example: say hyperplane H passes through the point $y = [1,4,2,5]$ and has a normal vector,$W = [−1,6,2,−4] $. $x$ is any other point on the hyperplane. vector on the plane is $x - y = [x-1,x-4,x-2,x-5]$ the equation of this hyperplane is simply $W^T(x-y) = 0$

otherwise, let's say if instead of being given a point on the hyperplane you were given the perpendicular distance,$d$ from the origin to the hyperplane and the normal vector,$W$ then you could use the following formula to find equation of the hyperplane $W^Tx = b$ where $b = d*||W||$ and $x$ is any point on the hyperplane.

Comment: “Gradient” is a common synonym for “slope,” which in this context is equivalent to “directional derivative.”